# Storing Images as binary in DB from external URL

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server

I am currently in the midst of migrating a site from ZenCart to NopCommerce (PHP to .Net). I am writing a routine to transfer the products from one to the other. I have finished this now with only one aspect remaining, the images. In Zencart, the location of the image is stored in the database, but in NopCommerce its stored as a binary in the database.

Can anyone help with a way to write images to an SQL Server DB as binary from an external url.

Comment: there is no such thing as C#.Net. It's just "C#". It's also not necessary to put that in the title of your question, since you've got those in the tags.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily use the [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) class or the [`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx)/[`HttpWebResponse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.aspx) to fetch the images at a particular url.

You would call the [`DownloadData` method on the `WebClient` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloaddata%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) or call the [`GetResponseStream` method on the `HttpWebResponse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.getresponsestream.aspx) returned from a call to [`HttpWebRequest.GetResponse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse.aspx) to get the bytes.

Then, you can insert the blobs into your DB as normal.